# Prove: Let  ∈ ℤ and a, b be distinct primes. Then a| and b| if and only if ab|.

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Consider the following theorem:
For every prime $p$ and all integers $a$, $b$, if $p\mid ab$, then $p\mid a$ or $p \mid b$.
Use it to prove the following proposition:
Prove: Let $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $w$, $y$ be distinct primes. Then $w\mid x$ and $y\mid x$ if and only if $wy\mid x$.

I am confused even as to what this is asking, from my understanding is it like the $p\mid ab$ but reversed? How would this then be proven?

Comment: One direction of the logical equivalence, "$w|x$ and $y|x$ if and only if $wy|x$" is much easier than the other.  You say you are "confused even as to what this is asking."  Do you understand the notation, where "$a|x$" means that $a$ exactly divides $c$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)